# Segmentation fault: 11 when assigning label value from array

Tags: arrays, swift, segmentation-fault

Having a hard time figuring this out.  I can print the value of an array and I can assign a label a string, but can't assign a label a value from the array.

```
print(self.items[0]["username"]) // prints username just fine
cell.UsernameLabel.text = "test" // works as expected too
cell.UsernameLabel.text = self.items[0]["username"] // throws Segmentation fault:11 on compilation
```

Comment: Please give more detail about the error info

Comment: What's the type of `self.items`?

Comment: I simply use `var items = []`.  I populate the array like this: `self.items = JSON as! NSArray;`

Comment: @David You should be conditionally downcasting your array to a native Swift array rather than using `NSArray`. Although nonetheless this is a compiler bug and you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: @originaluser2 I will do just that and I will file the bug report.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by downcasting:

```
cell.UsernameLabel.text = self.items[0]["username"] as? String
```

Comment: This works because the compiler needed to know some type information and you hadn't previously given it any...